# How to set a plot widget to Power Spectrum mode in PyQtGraph?

Tags: python, plot, pyqtgraph

I have data being plotted and I need to display its Fourier transform in real time. Right clicking on the plot and going through the Plot Options menu lets me select Power Spectrum mode, but is there any way to have this mode be active when the plot widget is created in the first place? I need the Fourier transform to be displayed without having to go through the clickable menus. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like this has been out there a while, but since it's something others can eventually benefit from, I'll add my 2 cents:

Easiest way I found to accomplish this is with programmatically hitting the check box just after creating the plot.  The PlotItem created has a self.ctrl menu, so doing a:

```
pitem.ctrl.fftCheck.setChecked(True)
```

should do the trick.

pitem is a reference returned by the addPlot method of a GraphicsLayout.  If you take a look at Plotting.py in their provided examples, "https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/examples/Plotting.py"
line 58:

```
p6 = win.addPlot(title="Updating plot")
```

p6 in this case is a PlotItem, so adding the following line in that case:

```
p6.ctrl.fftCheck.setChecked(True)
```

would do it.

For a second way to accomplish, notice also the next line in the example (line 59):

```
curve = p6.plot(pen='y')
```

You could accomplish FFT mode by using the PlotDataItem reference returned there via:

```
curve.setFftMode(True)
```

But this actually leaves the check mark in the menu unchecked, and can be a little confusing.

Yet a third way is on line 64:

```
curve.setData(data[ptr%10])
```

which would become:

```
curve.setData(data[ptr%10],fftMode=True)
```

These are all mutually exclusive, so performing any should work, but with the last 2 options it leaves the check mark in the menu unchecked, so again, option 1 is your best bet.

Comment: I should note that this option is very limited, unless you decide to subclass PlotDataItem to re-do their FFT.  Most times you're better off using numpy to perform the FFT's prior to the graph and just using pyqtgraph to plot the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on this first option given, if you are using a PlotWidget class instead of a PlotItem ( if you, like me, are using QtDesigner combined with Pyqtgraph to make your GUI), this can also be done, you just have to add getPlotItem() to access to the ctrl attribute.

For example, if my plot item is called `self.ui4.plot_1` (plot_1 is the label or name established in QtDesigner for the PlotWidget plot), you'll have to write:

```
self.ui4.plot_1.getPlotItem().ctrl.fftCheck.setChecked(True)
```